# How to show message if no data found on specific object key

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an array of object , first two object have full values but third object have missed one value . I will attach my array , what I want to show if there is no values then I want to show message .

**Array**

```
   let a= [{name:'Abc',address:'address 1'},{name:'name 2',address:'address 2'},{name:'name 3'}]

    a.map((item)=><div><span>{item.name}</span> <span>{item.address}</div>)
```

**Expected Result**

```
* Abc        address 1
* name 2     address 2
* name 3     not found
```

If you see at object# 3 in array you will see that address key is missing . If it missed I want to show message `not found` . Could someone please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can just test if the address is `undefined`. Display `"not found"` if it is `undefined` otherwise display the value of `item.address`.

```js
a.map((item)=><div><span>{item.name}</span> <span>{item.address === undefined ? 'not found': item.address }</div>)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `item.address` with `item.address || 'not found'`.

The reason this will work is because when `item.address` is missing, it will evaluate to `undefined` which is falsy.  For `||` it will evaluate until the the first truthy input or the last input, and so it will be 'not found' when not found.

Answer (score 0):

Just simple as this

```
let a= [{name:'Abc',address:'address 1'},{name:'name 2',address:'address 2'},{name:'name 3'}]

a.map((item)=> <div><span>{item.name}</span> <span>{item.address || "not found"}</div>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a truthy check

```
{ item.address || "not found" }
```

or use a typeof check

```
{ typeof item.address === 'undefined' ? 'not found' : item.address }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
 { a.map((item, index)=>
               (<div key={index}>
                  <span>{item.name}</span> 
                  <span>{item.address? item.address: 'not found'}</span>
                </div>))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below approach,

```
let a= [{name:'Abc',address:'address 1'},{name:'name 2',address:'address 2'},{name:'name 3'}]

a.map(({name, address})=>  

 <div><span>{name}</span> 
     <span>{address ? address : 'not found'}</span></div>)
```